# Silverlight MVVM - Twoway binding not fired on Listbox click

Tags: silverlight, binding, mvvm-light

In a Silverlight MVVMLight 4.0 application I have a listbox, a textbox and a checkbox.
The listbox's ItemsSource is bound to a list of objects in the viewmodel.
The listbox's SelectedItem is two-way bound to an object (SelectedActivity) in the viewmodel.

Both the textbox's Text and the checkbox's IsSelected properties are two-way bound to the SelectedActivity object (Name and Selected properties) in the viewmodel.
There is no codebehind.

This works fine:  changing the Name in the textbox or checking/unchecking the checkbox and then tabbing will change the underlying property of the object.

But when I change the name (or the checked state) and then immediatelly click another item in the list, the change is not registered.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

kind regards,

Karel

This is the XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="251" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,39,0,0" Name="activitiesListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities.Items}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Activities.SelectedActivity, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

This is the Activities class holding the items bound to the list:

```
public class CLJActivitiesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ActivitiesViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public CLJActivitiesViewModel()
    {
        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real": Connect to service, etc...
        ////}
    }


    #region items
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Items" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";

    private ObservableCollection<CLJActivityViewModel> m_Items = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Items property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<CLJActivityViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (m_Items == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = m_Items;
            m_Items = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region SelectedActivity
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedActivity" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SelectedActivityPropertyName = "SelectedActivity";

    private CLJActivityViewModel m_SelectedActivity = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the SelectedActivity property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public CLJActivityViewModel SelectedActivity
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedActivity;
        }

        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedActivity == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldValue = m_SelectedActivity;
            m_SelectedActivity = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedActivityPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }
    #endregion



    public override void Cleanup()
    {
        // Clean own resources if needed

        base.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted at least the relevant part of your viewmodel/view code. Is your list an ObservableCollection and your viewmodel implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, the list is bound to an ObservableCollection and the viewmodel is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  I used the MVVMLight templates.
I'll update the question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the kinda the same issue. I had to trigger the update as the user was entering text so that I could do some validation.

An easy way to achieve that is to create a custom behaviour that you can then add to any `TextBox`.

Mine is as follows:

```
public static class TextChangedBindingBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Instance", typeof(object), typeof(TextChangedBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSetInstanceCallback));


    public static object GetInstance(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(InstanceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInstance(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InstanceProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSetInstanceCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = d as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
            textBox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;

        if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(textBox))
        {
            textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

and you set it to the `TextBox` like that (`Behaviors` is the namespace where I put the class above):

```
 <TextBox Behaviors:TextChangedBindingBehavior.Instance="" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the issue like that with TextBox, but didn't see it affecting check box. TextBox issue is happening because bound text gets updated then focus is lost. That is why if you tab first and then change your selection it works as you expect. If you change selection directly bound text doesn't get updated since focus lost message arrives too late.

One way of dealing with this issue is to force binding update every time user types text in the text box. You can make custom behaviour to keep it mvvm.